# SQLite : Get all entries in a row

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Suppose I have an `SQLite` table `email_db` with 2 columns - `email` and `name`. How can I construct a `query` to get all records in the column `email`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select email from email_db` assuming you are using rawQuery.

Comment: like this `database.rawQuery("SELECT "+BaseColumns._ID+ " FROM " + DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] { "" });`?

Comment: Cursor cr  = database.rawQuery("SELECT email from email_db");

Answer (score 0):

Ff you are using `Cursor`:

```
Cursor c = getContentProvider().query(DB_URI, new String[]{"email"}, null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    // whatever
  } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```